# NetBackup license error despite license installed

Tags: netbackup

have been using NetBackup with for a few months now. So far I have been running NetBackup on a single server.

Back-ups on guest are perfect, I would like to use NetBackups VMWare Support as well, so I installed NetBackup Media Server on a Windows 2003 Server. After following the documentation, I succesfully added the media server on the Master server and successfully added a storage unit. Back-ups give the following error though.

```
07/31/2011 00:27:08 - requesting resource windisk1
07/31/2011 00:27:08 - requesting resource netbackup.NBU_CLIENT.MAXJOBS.plesk01
07/31/2011 00:27:08 - requesting resource netbackup.NBU_POLICY.MAXJOBS.filebackup01
07/31/2011 00:27:11 - Error nbjm (pid=5281) NBU status: 159, EMM status: Server is not licensed for Remote Client Option
licensed use has been exceeded  (159)
```

Hardware:

- NetBackup Master + Media Server - RHEL 5 x64 NetBackup Additional
- Media Server - Windows Server 2003 R2 64

License:

- Feature ID      = 71 Remote Client Support +

As you can see the license is configured and installed perfectly fine. How do I go about troubleshooting from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH55981) Symantec kb article may have solution to your problem.

Alternatively, depending on your license, see [this](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/licensed-use-has-been-exceeded-159) community thread. Googling for your error message gives a lot of articles with possible causes and solutions.

Comment: Yep, but I have googled. I have the right license, almost all Google posters didn't.